# Close an Excel file from a network drive via a user form

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform in Excel, which acts as a data entry mechanism . This data is saved in an Excel sheet, on a shared drive.  So it's a UI and data store, both in Excel .

Since we may have multiple users before I publish the data from userform to the Excel in-network drive, I check if the file is open in any Excel instance, and if yes, I want to close the Excel file so I don't have concurrency issues .

```
Dim bFileOpen As Boolean
    bFileOpen = IsWorkBookOpen("\\NTSYDFSP150\Shared\fmd\credit\LEM_Reports\SV Test\Test.xlsx")

    If bFileOpen Then
        MsgBox "File is open and is being closed now "

        Workbooks("\\NTSYDFSP150\Shared\fmd\credit\LEM_Reports\SV Test\Test.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=False

End If


Function IsWorkBookOpen(FileName As String)
    Dim ff As Long
    Dim ErrNo As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    ff = FreeFile()
    Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #ff
    Close ff
    ErrNo = Err
    On Error GoTo 0

    Select Case ErrNo
        Case 0
    IsWorkBookOpen = False
        Case 70
    IsWorkBookOpen = True
    Case Else
    End Select
End Function
```

I get an error on the following line:

`Workbooks("\\NTSYDFSP150\Shared\fmd\credit\LEM_Reports\SV Test\Test.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=False`

saying:

> subscript out of range

Comment: There is no way to do that - the person who has it open has to close it. You will have to come up with another method to updating it. This is one reason why databases were created, to avoid problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Workbooks("\\NTSYDFSP150\Shared\fmd\credit\LEM_Reports\SV Test\Test.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=False
> ```

That's implicitly:

```
Application.Workbooks(...).Close SaveChanges:=False
```

The `Workbooks` collection you're querying is the collection of all workbooks opened *in the current application instance*.

There is no way to close a workbook that's opened in another `Application` instance without first getting ahold of that `Application` object... and that isn't going to be possible over a network: you're asking your VBA code to go and shut down an application process that's running on another computer - without some serious admin privileges, I don't see how you could do that.

Consider using Microsoft Access, or having a SQL Server back-end for this kind of thing instead.